# Windows Firewall to block Semalt, Fraud countries, spam, hacking and more

Tags: vbscript, block, firewall, countries

I've found a .VBS script to protect my server but I'm not a programmer.
**This script blocks Fraud countries, Anonymous Proxy and Semalt infected servers.**
Our server is only intended for the European market.
*Can somebody tell me if this script works correctly (by testing it) or advice what can be better and tell me how I can check the blocked connections?*
I've added all the source files into a .rar file.
My system is Windows 8.1 x64 with an Wamp Apache server.
Thanks for all your support...

```css
> @echo off
> cls
> echo If you using a x32 system you need a x32 version, please download: http://www.maxmind.com/GeoIP-COM-1.3.zip
> echo and rename in this script SysWoW64 into system32
> echo.
> echo First we need to add GeoIpComEx.dll to the Windows register
> echo For more documentation please read: http://www.maxmind.com/GeoIP_MSCOM_64bit.pdf
> echo Copy GeoIpComEx.dll to your %systemroot%\SysWoW64\ directory
> pause
> %systemroot%\SysWoW64\regsvr32 /s /c "c:\windows\syswow64\GeoIpComEx.dll"
> echo GeoIpComEx.dll added to the Windows register
> pause
> cls
> echo Create a directory c:\wamp\geoip
> echo Copy all the *.dat files from: http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/legacy/geolite/#Downloads
> echo and ftp://ftp.mrunix.net/pub/webalizer/geodb/ to the directory c:\Wamp\geoip
> echo.
> pause
> cls
> echo So you have downloaded all the *.dat files into the dir c:\wamp\geoip
> echo geodb.dat
> echo geoip.dat
> echo geoip.inc
> echo geoipasnum.dat
> echo geoipasnumv6.dat
> echo geoipcity.inc
> echo geoipv6.dat
> echo geolitecity.dat
> echo geolitecityv6.dat
> pause
> cls
> echo Because Win7 and Win8 has a problem to execute .VBS files we have to rename the script.exe files
> echo Rename cscript.exe into csadmin.exe
> rename "%systemroot%\SysWoW64\cscript.exe" "%systemroot%\SysWoW64\csadmin.exe"
> echo Rename wscript.exe into wsadmin.exe
> rename "%systemroot%\SysWoW64\wscript.exe" "%systemroot%\SysWoW64\wsadmin.exe"
> echo With Windows explorer give the files %systemroot%\SysWoW64\wscript.exe and %systemroot%\SysWoW64\wsadmin.exe > "admin rights"
> pause
> cls
> echo Now we execute the .vbs script %systemroot%\SysWoW64\csadmin.exe with geoip_block_countries1.vbs
> %systemroot%\SysWoW64\csadmin.exe //Nologo //B c:\wamp\vbs_firewall\geoip_block_countries1.vbs
> pause
> cls
> echo Please look in your log to see which countries were blocked.
> echo Add %systemroot%\SysWoW64\csadmin.exe //Nologo //B c:\wamp\vbs_firewall\geoip_block_countries1.vbs into your taskmanager when startup
> echo or start test_geoip_vbs2.cmd manuel after startup
> echo Reboot your PC/server
> pause
```

[Complete script with all the needed files](http://www.webshopdesigners.nl/Protect_your_server.rar)

Comment: Thanks for all the positive responses. The script seems to work well. The script protects your Mail-server, FTP-server, Web-server (Apache/IIS, Xampp/Wamp), PC / laptop against spam and hacking from fraud countries.

Best regards,
Rolf

Comment: it's a stand alone script . It doesn't block Google, Bing, Yahoo, Facebook, Twitter etc. The script can easily be combined with ModSecurity > https://www.modsecurity.org/

Comment: This script checks where the visitor is comming from based on the IPnumber. Is the visitor comming from a fraud country then the script will drop the connection to your Mail/FTP/Web-server.
This is based on MaxMind GeoLite Country:
http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/legacy/geolite/#Downloads
and WebAlizer geodb.dat: ftp://ftp.mrunix.net/pub/webalizer/geodb/

Comment: I use Maxmind site to block or add countries:
http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/legacy/codes/iso3166/